# What happens if we on cum out side without inserting in in ramzan

Tags: sex, sawm, ramadan, husband-wife

if we kiss our wife and just about to have sex and unintentional ejculate not inserting inside. Will I have to go for kaffarah? Or i have to do qaza?First. Did i break my fast?

Comment: I suppose you did this while fasting?

Comment: Yes it was while fasting

Answer (score 1):

وَعَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ ‏- رضى  الله عنه ‏- قَالَ: { جَاءَ رَجُلٌ إِلَى اَلنَّبِيِّ ‏- صلى الله عليه  وسلم ‏-فَقَالَ: هَلَكْتُ يَا رَسُولَ اَللَّهِ.‏ قَالَ: " وَمَا  أَهْلَكَكَ ? " قَالَ: وَقَعْتُ عَلَى اِمْرَأَتِي فِي رَمَضَانَ، فَقَالَ:  " هَلْ تَجِدُ مَا تَعْتِقُ رَقَبَةً? " قَالَ: لَا.‏ قَالَ: " فَهَلْ  تَسْتَطِيعُ أَنْ تَصُومَ شَهْرَيْنِ مُتَتَابِعَيْنِ? " قَالَ: لَا.‏  قَالَ: " فَهَلْ تَجِدُ مَا تُطْعِمُ سِتِّينَ مِسْكِينًا? " قَالَ: لَا,  ثُمَّ جَلَسَ, فَأُتِي اَلنَّبِيُّ ‏- صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏-بِعَرَقٍ فِيهِ  تَمْرٌ.‏ فَقَالَ: " تَصَدَّقْ بِهَذَا ", فَقَالَ: أَعَلَى أَفْقَرَ  مِنَّا? فَمَا بَيْنَ لَابَتَيْهَا أَهْلُ بَيْتٍ أَحْوَجُ إِلَيْهِ  مِنَّا, فَضَحِكَ اَلنَّبِيُّ ‏- صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏-حَتَّى بَدَتْ  أَنْيَابُهُ، ثُمَّ قَالَ: "اذْهَبْ فَأَطْعِمْهُ أَهْلَكَ " }  رَوَاهُ  اَلسَّبْعَةُ, وَاللَّفْظُ لِمُسْلِمٍ  1‏ .‏

Abu Hurairah (RAA) narrated that A man came to the  Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and said, “l am ruined O Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)!"  The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) asked him, “What has ruined you?" The man  replied, ‘I had intercourse with my wife during the day in Ramadan while  fasting)’ The Prophet said to him, "Are you able to free a slave?" The  man said, ‘No.’ The Prophet said, "Can you fast for two consecutive  months?" He said, ‘NO.' The Prophet then asked him, "Can you provide  food for sixty poor people?" He said, ‘No.’ Then the man sat down. A  basket of dates was brought to the Prophet and he said to the man, “Give  this as Sadaqah (voluntary charity)” The man said, ‘To someone who is  poorer than us!’ There is no one in this city (Al-Madinah) who is in  need of these dates more than us!’ The Prophet laughed until his molar  teeth could be seen and said to the man, “Go and feed your family with  these dates.” Related by the seven Imams and the wording is from Muslim.

Bulugh al-Maram
(Fasting)
English reference : Book 5, Hadith 697
Arabic reference : Book 5, Hadith 676

عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ رَضِيَ اللَّهُ عَنْهُ، عَنْ النَّبِيِّ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ قَالَ:
" يَقُولُ اللَّهُ عَزَّ  وَجَلَّ: الصَّوْمُ لِي، وَأَنَا أَجْزِي بِهِ، يَدَعُ شَهْوَتَهُ  وَأَكْلَهُ وَشُرْبَهُ مِنْ أَجْلِي، وَالصَّوْمُ جُنَّةٌ(1)،  وَلِلصَّائِمِ فَرْحَتَانِ: فَرْحَةٌ حِينَ يُفْطِرُ، وَفَرْحَةٌ حِينَ  يَلْقَى رَبَّهُ، وَلَخُلُوفُ(2) فَمِ الصَّائِمِ أَطْيَبُ عِنْدَ اللَّهِ  مِنْ رِيحِ الْمِسْكِ"
.
رواه البخاري (وكذلك مسلم ومالك والترمذي النسائي وابن ماجه)

On the authority of Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) from the Prophet (ﷺ), who said:

Allah (mighty and sublime be He) says: Fasting is Mine and it is I who give reward for it. [A man] gives up his  sexual passion, his food and his drink for my sake. Fasting is like a  shield, and he who fasts has two joys: a joy when he breaks his fast and  a joy when he meets his Lord. The change in the breath of the mouth of  him who fasts is better in Allah's estimation than the smell of musk.

It was related by al-Bukhari (also by Muslim, Malik, at-Tirmidhi,  an-Nasa'i and Ibn Majah).

40 Hadith Qudsi
(40 Hadith Qudsi)
Arabic/English book reference : Hadith 10

وَعَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ ‏- رضى  الله عنه ‏- قَالَ: قَالَ رَسُولُ اَللَّهِ ‏- صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏-{ مَنْ  نَسِيَ وَهُوَ صَائِمٌ, فَأَكَلَ أَوْ شَرِبَ, فَلْيُتِمَّ صَوْمَهُ,  فَإِنَّمَا أَطْعَمَهُ اَللَّهُ وَسَقَاهُ }  مُتَّفَقٌ عَلَيْهِ  1‏ .‏

Abu Hurairah (RAA) narrated that The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:

‘Whoever forgets that he is fasting, and eats or  drinks is to complete his fast, as it was Allah who fed him and gave him  something to drink." Agreed upon.

Bulugh al-Maram
(Fasting)
English reference : Book 5, Hadith 690
Arabic reference : Book 5, Hadith 669

وَعَنْ عَائِشَةَ رَضِيَ  اَللَّهُ عَنْهَا قَالَتْ: { كَانَ رَسُولُ اَللَّهِ ‏- صلى الله عليه وسلم  ‏-يُقَبِّلُ وَهُوَ صَائِمٌ, وَيُبَاشِرُ وَهُوَ صَائِمٌ, وَلَكِنَّهُ  أَمْلَكُكُمْ لِإِرْبِهِ }  مُتَّفَقٌ عَلَيْهِ, وَاللَّفْظُ لِمُسْلِمٍ  1‏ .‏
وَزَادَ فِي رِوَايَةٍ: { فِي رَمَضَانَ }   2‏ .‏

'A’isha (RAA) narrated that The Messenger of Allah  (ﷺ) would kiss and embrace (his wives) while fasting, for he had the  most control of all of you over his desires.’ Agreed upon and the  wording is from Muslim, who added in a narration, ‘In Ramadan.

Bulugh al-Maram
(Fasting)
English reference : Book 5, Hadith 685
Arabic reference : Book 5, Hadith 664

( You are not supposed to embrace your loved one until sunset, if you cannot control your desires. My advice would be to sincerely apologize with your heart and to make up the day and try harder. )

( and yes, you definitely broke your fast for that day at least.)

Comment: Evidences don't speak for themselves.

Comment: I added a little bit. To me these Evidences do speak for themselves in showing how to be rightly guided during such instances. But this also now that I have added some more.